# Mocking Sftp class skip method call

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, jsch

```
public class SFTP {

    public Map<Report, TransferStatus> transfer(List<Report> reports) {
       //testing logic here
     }

    private ChannelSftp channelSftp;
    private Session session;


    private TransferStatus send(File file) {
                connect();

                send(stream, file.getName());      
    }


    private void send(FileInputStream stream, String name) throws SftpException, IOException {

        channelSftp.put(stream, fileNameWithId, new SftpLogMonitor(), ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
        stream.close();
    }


    private void connect() throws JSchException {

        if (session != null && channelSftp != null) {
            return;
        }

        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        jsch.addIdentity(sftpConfig.getSftpPublicKey());

        session = jsch.getSession(sftpConfig.getSftpUser(), sftpConfig.getSftpHost(), Integer.parseInt(sftpConfig.getSftpPort()));

        session.setUserInfo(new JschUserInfo());
        session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        session.connect();

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.connect();
    }
```

Given the above, how can I avoid the calls to `JSch` objects. I want to avoid sending of the file to remote server and just want to validate test cases in `transfer()` method.

So far I have the following settings:

```
   private JSch jSch = mock(JSch.class);
    private Session session = mock(Session.class);
    private ChannelSftp sftp = mock(ChannelSftp.class);


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        when(jSch.getSession(eq(USERNAME), eq(HOSTNAME), eq(PORT))).thenReturn(session);
        when(session.openChannel("sftp")).thenReturn(sftp);
        //doNothing().when(sftp).put(Matchers.any());

    }
```

I don't want to exclude the call to `put()` or pass throw it to the next statement in the method.

Comment: when you mock the class under test, you have a problem. Just use a real SFTP instance here (and don't call `connect`). If your `transfer` method call `connect` then use a [Mockito "spy"](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Using-Spies-(and-Fakes)) to suppress the behavior of `connect`

Comment: `connect()` is called in `send()`. Can you show me?

Comment: Mockito cannot mock that `new JSch()` object that gets created by the `connect()` method. PowerMockito, however, can, if you want to use that (would basically require a `whenNew(JSch.class)` expectation to be recorded).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with using `mockito` here is that your `connect()` method depends on `new JSch()`. `Mockito` is not able to mock constructor calls.
But you can change that with a little workaround, as suggested in [Michael Feathers book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).
Just extract your `new JSch()` to the package private getter method

```
private void connect() throws JSchException {
    ...
    JSch jsch = getJSch();
    ...
}

JSch getJSch() {
    return new JSch();
}
```

Now in your test, you can override this method to return a mocked instance

```
private JSch jSch = mock(JSch.class);
private SFTP sftp = new SFTP(){
    @Override
    JSch getJSch() {
        return jSch;
    }
};
```

It's not the most elegant solution but it's the solution worth to consider. Especially if you don't want to do a lot of refactoring.

Answer (score -3):

You can use below command to get the mocked instance of Jsch:

```
@Mock
JSch jsch;

@Mock
ChannelSftp channelSftp;

@Mock
Session session;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    Whitebox.setInternalState(SftpConnection.class, "sftpUserName", "test1");
    Whitebox.setInternalState(SftpConnection.class, "sftpIpAddress", "test2");
    Whitebox.setInternalState(SftpConnection.class, "sftpPort", 0);
    Whitebox.setInternalState(SftpConnection.class, "sftpPortPassword", "test3");
    PowerMockito.whenNew(JSch.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(this.jsch);
    Mockito.when(this.jsch.getSession("test1", "test2", 0)).thenReturn(this.session);
    Mockito.when(this.session.openChannel("sftp")).thenReturn(this.channelSftp);
}
```